# How does Zapier, etc. store and refresh third party access tokens

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to understand how the OAuth integration with third-party apps works. For example, an application xyz can access gmail, notion, etc like how zapier and other apps do to perform tasks. I am attaching an image explaining my understanding.

[Image explaining my understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nvZ.png)

My doubts are about how we store the access_token and do we actively check the expiry and refresh it (like a scheduled job).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. How to store access tokens

It actually depends on the type of application that you build. A mobile or a desktop app would typically store the tokens in memory. You can even write them down to the disk (on a mobile you can save them in the secure module so it's harder to steal the tokens) if you want your app to be able to use the tokens after a restart. For browser-based apps, you can keep the token in memory or local/session storage. However, according to current best practice it's deemed unsafe. You should rather deploy a backend component that will manage the tokens and issue secure, HTTP-only cookies to your app. (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps)

2. Do you actively refresh tokens

Some people do it, they refresh the token before it expires. When you get a token response from the authorization server, you also get an `expires_in` field that tells you in how many seconds the token will expire. You can set a job that will refresh the token just before that time passes. Regardless, your API client should be able to handle token expiration responses. When you get a 401 response from the API it most probably means that the token is expired. You should first try to refresh the token and retry the API request with the new token. You should redirect the user to the login page only if the second request or the refresh request fail. This would happen if the refresh token expired or if the server invalidated tokens for some reason (maybe the signing keys rotated, etc.)